# Git - when to pull / where to pull from origin?

Tags: merge, gitlab, push, branch

We've just transitioned to a gitlab system. I pulled from master, created a branch, and am ready commit and request a merge. Before I commit, I want to pull changes that happened in the interim.

Question - do I switch back to the main branch to do the pull? Then switch back to the current branch? But if I do that, will it no longer of the the changes from the pull to main? And if I don't switch to the main branch, will I be committing code without the updated code?

Answer (score 1):

No need to switch to master (do they call it `main` branch now?), just do the following command from your current branch (replace master with main if your repo is post-BLM):

```
git merge origin/master
```

Answer (score 0):

On the Github desktop client, I did the following:

1. switch to master
2. pull
3. switch to branch
4. merge from master